# display a link to all the categories of current post, including parents

Tags: categories

amazingly, this seems to be hard, and I don't see the answer anywhere online.
simply list all the category of the current post (on single.php), but also all the parent categories of it.

```
<?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>
```

only lists and links to the subcategory the post is added to.

so, if a post is added to a subcategory called 'apples', and that category has a parent category called 'fruits', show and link to

> fruits >> apples

or, if its parent category has a parent category, list and link to that one too

> green >> fruits >> apples

simply said, list and link all of them, parent or child.

Update:  thanks to @Svartbaard answer for pointing me in the right direction, I passed the category id and it works:

```
<?php 
                 $categories = get_the_category();
                 $cat = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
                 echo get_category_parents( $cat, true, ' &raquo; ' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the following function

```
<?php echo get_category_parents( $cat, true, ' &raquo; ' ); ?>
```

where $cat is the id of the current category. This example if from the codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I passed the category id and it works